# Faster implementation, of tree height function

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, tree

i' m new to algorithm, and I developed such function for finding the tree height of the input sequence.

```
import sys, threading


class TreeHeight:
        def read(self):
                self.n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
                self.parent = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

        def compute_height(self):
                # Replace this code with a faster implementation
                maxHeight = 0
                for vertex in range(self.n):
                        height = 0
                        i = vertex
                        while i != -1:
                                height += 1
                                i = self.parent[i]
                        maxHeight = max(maxHeight, height)
                return maxHeight

def main():
  tree = TreeHeight()
  tree.read()
  print(tree.compute_height())

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

That works like this:

```
5
4 -1 4 1 1
```

And output

```
3
```

Because there are 5 nodes with numbers from 0 to 4, node 0 is a child of node 4, node 1 is the root,node 2 is a child of node 4, node 3 is a child of node 1 and node 4 is a child of node1. The height of this tree is 3, because the number of vertices on the path from root 1 to leaf 2 is 3

My solution is working, but it is not optimized for deep trees. For example, program crashes for input 100000.

What is the better solution in my case?

Comment: There's a difference between faster and not crashing. You should probably focus on the crashing first.

Comment: I thought that these two issues are connected, as the result of inefficient algorithm

Comment: Crashes how? It doesn't look like it should ever crash.

Comment: Maybe it goes in an infinite loop and the environment he's testing on kills his process. The code is baffling but it can definitely get in an infinite loop, just consider a tree containing 1 item solely 0.

Comment: Can you assume that the vertices are sorted? I.e. that a vertex' parent is located before the vertex? In that case, cache the intermediate tree heights, so you don't have to traverse all the way up to the root. This could be done more efficiently with a recursive approach because it does not store every single height. However, this would require child pointers.

Comment: Anyway your code basically inspects every node to determine it's height. Determining the height might require inspecting every node again. That's O(N^2). You should realize you don't need to calculate the height of a node more than once. Any time you know the height of a node, record it in another array. Any time you are trying to find the height of a node, and you find a node you've already calculated, you can stop calculating it. In your example, you will try to find the height of node 2, see its a child of node 1, and already know node 1 is at height 1. Easier said than done, but it helps.